# why am I getting prop id does not match what was rendered on the server error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js

[image]

I am building a nextjs redux project. I keep encountering this error whenever I refresh my page, I cant seem to find a solution. What exactly is happening, on the official next js blog I saw recommendations that say to ignore it because it only shows up in dev mode. Is this right ? if not, is there a solution ?

I am also using the HYDRATE special reducer, but it didn't resolve the issue.

```
const hydrate  = createAction<userState>(HYDRATE)


builder.addCase(hydrate, (state,action)=>{
        return {...state, ...action.payload}
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an error happening during the hydration phase in nextjs. During this process, next compares the generated html with what you've on the client and if there's any mismatch you get that error.

I think you can resolve this by trying this steps.

1. Make sure the data the components uses on the server and client matches.
2. If you're fetching data from nextjs app make sure you make use of 'getServerSideProps' properly.
3. Make sure client side code are properly handled using conditions I mean if you're using window or document object in these case.

Also it's worth taking a look at this thread. [GitHub nextjs issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/12863)